# changing representation of Node Objects in the REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to make "moment" objects representation shorter, because I have a data structure which contains many of them and I wish i could make its representation more compact.

Example:

```
node-repl>  d = new Date()
2018-05-29T12:50:12.111Z 
node-repl> m = moment(d)
=> VERY LONG THING IN OUTPUT
```

Now imagine you have many moment objects "m1", "m2" ...  and they are spread into a data structureas l = ["hello", m1, "world", m2, m3...].
Reading list "l" becomes difficult.

I would like a "moment" obejct to be printed by default in the REPL as "moment DD-MM-YYYY".

It should be something similar to this, but I don't know how to make it right.

```
moment.prototype.toString = function() {
   var dd = this.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
   var out = "moment-" + dd;
   return out;
}
```

Do you have any advice ?

Comment: What did you triìed so far? Have a look at the docs, I think you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: wait wait, maybe my question is not clear, I add some text to the original body.

Comment: I found some useful directions here: (https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_customizing_repl_output)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I don't understand all the fecets of how this works, but it works.

```
moment.prototype[util.inspect.custom] = function(depth, options) {
 var tmp = this.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
 tmp = `moment<${tmp}>`;
 var out = options.stylize(tmp, 'special');
 return out;
}
```